# What should I use: "nehmen" or "werden"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

In English we would say I plan to **take** a later airplane flight.
Would the German translation use *nehmen* or *werden*, or something else.

Comment: How did you come up with "werden". "Take" is never translated as "werden". Not at all. In the sense of "travel", "take" is (nearly always) translated as "nehmen".

Comment: I used Google translate, but the answer seemed off, hence I consulted the experts here.  My apologies if the question is off-topic (but thanks to all for the insights and help!)

Answer (score 2):

- "Er **wird** ein späteres **nehmen**" verwendet beides.
- "Er **plant** ein späteres **zu nehmen**" geht auch, oder
- "Er **plant** in einem späteren Flugzeug **zu sein**" und
- "Er **wird** in einem späteren Flugzeug **sein**".

Answer (score 1):

You can say "Ich fliege mit dem Flugzeug" oder "Ich nehme das Flugzeug".

(Note that you cannot literally translate "to go by plane" as "mit dem Flugzeug gehen"; "gehen" bedeutet immer mit den Füßen.)

Comment: It is funny that I always hear the inverse caution: That _go_ is more limited in English, where it always means actual walking. :) Consider something like _Zum Studium ist er nach Berlin gegangen_, _Ich gehe jetzt nach Hause_.

Comment: @chirlu And? Isn't that a valid remark when someone asks for verbs in means of transportation?